# Deploying Linux game, shared libraries/dependencies

Tags: linux, sdl

I have a cross-platform application (game). It uses SDL library. I can't link it statically due to LGPL licence. On Windows I bundle DLL file, on Mac OSX I bundle Frameworks directory. But how can it be resolved on GNU/Linux? If user have no SDL libraries installed on his system there is an error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Even if I bundle .so file, system doesn't seem to use it.

Another problem is that I don't want to forcibly override user libraries. SDL is not a problem, but for example OpenAL libraries vary greatly, and user can have working OpenAL libraries while mine could crash on his machine.

Comment: Where are you placing the `.so` files? The system will only find them if it's in the search path.

Comment: In the same directory as an executable. I don't want to install anything into system path because I don't want to require root access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Linux doesn't search the current directory nor the directory from which the binary is run. If you want the easy approach, do this:

```
$> LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your.so programName
```

The correct approach is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which is a colon delimited list of search paths. Add the path of your libraries to this list.

```
$> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/your/libs"
$> programName
```

If you really want to get creative, your binary can actually contain its own search path if you configure it properly:

http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html

Answer (score 1):

There's also [$ORIGIN](http://blog.linuxgamepublishing.com/2009/02/08/our-new-way-to-meet-the-lgpl/).

Answer (score 1):

This solution depends on exactly what Linux distribution you are using (more specifically what package manager), but I think it is the "cleanest" solution to your problem:

Make a package containing your application (on Ubuntu or Debian this would be a .deb package to use with apt). This way you can set dependencies on shared libraries. You won't have to deploy SDL/OpenAL yourself, and if these packages are released in newer versions, you wont have to update your own package. This way your application will be much smaller and easier to distribute, and if SDL/OpenAL are not present on the target system, they will be installed. The downside is that your application is not self-contained.

Comment: This is actually very sensible answer. While I don't want to assume any specific distribution, having not only zipped binary but also .deb package would be very helpful for Ubuntu/Debian users -- and I think those distributions are one of the most popular.

Comment: @John: I recommend checking out the Ubuntu resources on how to do this: [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide). It is quite a read, but some parts of it can be simplified (using CDBS to set rules for example). Some make systems such as CMake or [qmake](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/QtApplication) have additional tools that make this process easier. It can also be a good idea to create the .deb package using pbuilder. This way you ensure the package will work on another system (that all dependencies are correctly defined in the .deb)